# snd_hda_intel spurious response on audio start/stop

Tags: sound, kernel, 18.04

My `kern.log` has tons of entries like:

```
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: spurious response 0x200:0x0, last cmd=0x1f0500
snd_hdac_bus_update_rirb: 67 callbacks suppressed
```

I'm running 18.04, but I have noticed these since 16.04.
HDMI Audio, pulseAudio.

**Audio device:** Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)

These occur whenever sound starts or stops. You can trigger them by testing your speakers with the Settings app. The audio is fine, but I am trying to resolve other issues and these entries,besides being voluminous, make we wonder if they could cause undesirable side effects.

Should I be concerned? Can I disable the messages?